# how to align text in PIL pictures

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to output text to pictures with PIL. I was able to save the texts to png pictures but they are not aligned correctly.

Here is the code:

```
size = (2000, 500)
W, H = size
clear = PIL.Image.new(mode="RGB", size=size, color=(255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(clear)
font = ImageFont.truetype("ARIAL.TTF", size=20)
_, _, w, h = draw.textbbox((0, 0), formated_terminal_info, font=font)
draw.text(
    ((W - w) / 2, (H - h) / 2),
    formated_terminal_info,
    font=font,
    fill="black",
    align="left",
)
clear.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

I was able to format `formated_terminal_info` correctly in the terminal, and it looks like this:
[image: formated_string_in_terminal]

However, the PIL picture I got looks like this:
[image: formated_string_in_PIL_picture]

I'm wondering if I can get the text in the picture aligned correctly like they are displayed in the terminal.

Comment: Just a heads-up: There are tools which do something similar like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138809/61956 and another one which I can't find right now.

Comment: @DanielF Thanks for the tip. I'd prefer solving it within the ability of PIL. I'll use these tools as a backup plan if my purpose can not be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Monotype font, which is what terminals use to align each letter. With fonts like Arial, a lowercase L is less wide than an uppercase L, messing up the alignment.

Comment: YES! That's the reason. I thought about the font and changed a few but did not fix it so I thought all the fonts does the same. Turns out the only monospaced TrueType fonts shipped by Microsoft are Courier New. I changed to it and it worked! Thanks so much.